# How to install logstash on Suse

Tags: logstash, sles

I am trying to install logstash on SLES . Here are the version details

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 2
# This file is deprecated and will be removed in a future service pack or release.
# Please check /etc/os-release for details about this release.
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp2"
```

Most of the instructions available over google are for ElasticSearch but not for logstash. I tried rpm based installation as described here `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html` but here too they install elasticsearch using `zypper install elasticsearch` I am trying to install logstash 6.1 or later. what is the best way to install logstash on SLES? While installaing elasticsearch too I get an error as follows:

`elasticsearch-6.1.3-1.noarch (Elasticsearch repository for 6.x packages): Signature verification failed [4-Signatures public key is not available]`

Here is my elasticsearch.repo

```
[elasticsearch-6.x]
name=Elasticsearch repository for 6.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late, but it's better late than never. Anyway, I had the same issue and this article gave me an idea for a solution: https://en.opensuse.org/User:Tsu2/elasticsearch_logstash_official_repos. This part specifically solved my issue:

> - Download TAR file and extract. Because Elasticsearch is a Java binary, the extracted files can be run from anywhere

So, what I did is I've downloaded the Logstash TAR file, SCPed it to my SUSE server, and extracted it to my ELK folder. Then I ran it using its bin/logstash executable.

I hope this solution helps you and others who stumble on this page on their search for the solution.